# How to pass value to the react nativ webview body

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I want to pass a value from react-native to webview

```
<WebView
  source={{
    uri: 'https://accountant.aqilz.com/add-new-submit-form.php',
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'cat=cat',
  }}
/>
```

Instead of hardcoded value cat=cat in the above code, I need to pass value from `myId`.

```
const myId = this.props.route.params.email;
<WebView
  source={{
    uri: 'abcd.com/add-new-submit-form.php',
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'cat=???',
  }}
/>
```

I want to pass the value from the **const** to the webview **body**. By doing this I can able to retrieve the login user email id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template literals:

```
const myId = this.props.route.params.email;
<WebView
  source={{
    uri: 'abcd.com/add-new-submit-form.php',
    method: 'POST',
    body: `cat=${myId}`,
  }}
/>
```

You can also use standard string concatenation:

```
// ...
body: "cat=" + myId,
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked exactly as i want

Comment: Can you accept the answer since it solved the problem?